# Postgresql update trigger not accepting When / OF condition

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger but getting syntax error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER archive_domain_trig
  AFTER UPDATE OF is_rejected ON pending_domains
  FOR EACH ROW 
  WHEN (new.is_rejected is True)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE archive_domain_fun();
```

ERROR: syntax error at or near "OF"

not only this but it is giving error on "when" condition also e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER archive_domain_trig
  AFTER UPDATE ON pending_domains
  FOR EACH ROW 
  WHEN (new.is_rejected is True)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE archive_domain_fun();
```

gives:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHEN".

```
select version();
"EnterpriseDB 8.3.0.116 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.1.0"
```

This is almost similar to postgres example, can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that EnterpriseDB 8.3 is the EnterpriseDB version of PostgreSQL 8.3. Conditional triggers (i.e. the `WHEN` option) are a new feature in PostgreSQL 9.0. Compare the CREATE TRIGGER documentation for [8.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) and [9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html).